# Django - null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint (Image uploading)

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get my head around how to upload and post an image through my Django form. I have sussed out how to post content, but not Images.

At the moment, when I try to upload an image with my Post, the following error is returned:

```
null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Views.py

```
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
   

    model = Post
    fields = ['content', 'image']
    template_name = 'core/post_new.html'
    success_url = '/'

    @login_required
    def post_image(request):
        
        form=upl()
    
        if request.method == 'POST':
              form = upl(request.POST, request.FILES)
              
            upl.save()
       
        return render(request, 'core/post_new.html', {'form': form})

    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author_id = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['tag_line'] = 'Create new post'
        return data
```

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='core_media')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content[:5]

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

**UPDATED Views.py**

```
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
   
    model = Post
    fields = ['content', 'image']
    template_name = 'core/post_new.html'
    success_url = '/'

@login_required
    def post_image(request):
    form=upl()

    if request.method == 'POST':
          form = upl(request.POST, request.FILES)
          
    upl.save()
   
    return render(request, 'core/post_new.html', {'form': form})

    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author_id = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['tag_line'] = 'Create new post'
        return data
```

Any assistance/direction would be most appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: indent the `@login_required` properly as a *method* of the class, right now the `form_valid` is a function *inside* the `post_image` function.

Comment: Ah thank you! Sorry everything is a little scattered at the moment, I'm just trying to reference as many tutorials as I can, but I have a habit of putting certain bits of code in the wrong places. I'll try your suggestion now! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `form_valid` and `get_context_data` are here *no* members of your `CreatePostView`, but inner functions of the `post_image` function.

You should implement this as:

```
class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['content', 'image']
    template_name = 'core/post_new.html'
    success_url = '/'

    #   ↓        ↓ method of the CreatePostView
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    #   ↓              ↓ method of the CreatePostView
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['tag_line'] = 'Create new post'
        return data
```

Comment: Hello Willem! Thank you for your response! I have updated my original question with an updated Views.py file (based on the code you provided me with) does the format of my code look a little better now? :-) I'll have to buy a you a few coffees if you accept donations :)

Comment: @Jarjar95: exactly what is `post_image(request):` doing here? It looks like a different view.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to achieve a form which allows you to write text in to the "content" field and at the same time, I want to be able to upload an image which displays together with the post content (within the same form). The "post_image" bit there, is my attempt at trying to get my uploaded image to save. But I think i've got it a little wrong!

Comment: What if you remove the `post_image` method (and the code in that method, and the `@login_required` decorator)?

Comment: So I've just removed the method and the code within (and have also removed the `@login_required` - And my form appears, (The form displays my Content field and Image field) but after I write in some content, upload an image and hit the submit button, I receive this error - IntegrityError -  null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: @Jarjar95: but the `def form_valid(self, form):` method is still in your `CreatePostView` class? What if you use `form.instance.author = self.request.user` (so *without the `_id` part)?

Comment: That's correct, the `def form_valid(self, form):` method still exists within my CreatePostView class. I've tried removing the `_id` but still get the same error. Here's the exact error: null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (26, sdhsdhdshdsh, 2021-05-25 15:58:01.053625+00, 0, 0, null, default.png)`    (The scrambled bit of writing after where it says 26, is just some dummy content I entered in to the text box)

Comment: @Jarjar95: can you edit the question with the current state of the (entire) view?

Comment: Hey Willem! I finally got it working!!! :-D I noticed that in my forms.py file, I hadn't added `enctype="multipart/form-data"`and I also had a redundant name tag on my form which I removed and the error has gone! Photos are uploading and I've added the relevant template tags for where I want my photos to appear. All is working great, but a huge thanks goes out to you! If i can send any donations your way, please let me know! I will be happy to do so! :-)